# Chaining promises

Tags: node.js, promise, q

What I want to achieve is parsing a given website and writing its title to `titles.txt`. I am using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module for fetching the website and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) for getting the title.

I am using the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) module for creating the following two promises:

**readTitle**

```
var readTitle = function(url) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    request({
        url: url
    }, function(err, response, body) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        deferred.resolve($("title").text());
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

**writeTitle**

```
var writeTitle = function(title) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    fs.appendFile('titles.txt', title + "\n", function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I expect the following script to write `Google` and `Stack Overflow` to the text file:

```
readTitle('http://www.google.com')
.then(writeTitle)
.then(readTitle('http://www.stackoverflow.com'))
.then(writeTitle);
```

But what I actually get is:

```
Google
undefined
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Just guessing: `.then(readTitle('http://www.stackoverflow.com').then(writeTitle));`.

Comment: You should be passing a function reference (a function that is not yet called) to `.then()`, not an executed function.  So, if you need arguments on your function, then pass it like this: `.then(function() {return readTitle('http://www.stackoverflow.com')})`.

Comment: This code could be much simpler, would you accept a Bluebird promises olution?

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't provide the behavior you had in your question. Instead, it fires both promises simultaneously. RobertLevy's answer is more correct. You can shorten it with bind. Also worth mentioning, your manual promisification silences errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`then` needs to be passed a function rather than a value

```
.then(function() {return readTitle('http://www.stackoverflow.com'); })
.then(writeTitle);
```

Comment: This answer is actually the only correct one at the moment, that first `.then` can be written as `.then(readTitle.bind(null,'http://www.stackoverflow.com'))` if performance doesn't matter - which I assume is the case here since otherwise no one would be using Q over a fast promise library anyway.

Comment: bloodKnuckles was correct. I accepted his answer. I do care for performance, Benjamin. I am guessing you prefer Bluebird? Why? Is there any proof that it is actually faster?

Comment: @Amberlamps only if you consider benchmarks ^^  https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/benchmark/stats/latest.md It's two orders of magnitude faster, has a lot of useful collection methods and is a lot more debuggable with better stack traces and unhandled rejection detection.

Comment: @Amberlamps also, bloodKnuckles was incorrect, if you want to fire both requests in parallel there is a good way to do that too.